How do I pass information to TestNG IAnnotationTrasformer?
I just discovered that the implementation of listener with IAnnotationTransformer annotation is executed as soon as the tests are launched even before the very first test is executed.
Background:  I have added about 10 new tests named homePageTest_01( ) through homePageTest_10( ) to my automated test suite.  However, I need to disable a certain number of them depending on a specific condition. The listener’s implementation is designed to disable execution if a method name contains certain string – which in this example would be “homePageTest_”.
Question: Out of these 10 new tests I want to execute only first 5 tests – and want the listener to disable the execution of tests 06 through 10 depending on certain condition. Since the listener is executed before even the tests are executed, how can I pass the details of such condition to the listener?
So far I have tried to pass the details of the condition using the -D argument on the command line – and retrieve the value in the listener – but details cannot be found at execution time.  May be the JVM is not ready when this listener is executed!?
Any suggestions for me?
Thanks, Sam.
